# Scalar theory with non-trivial boundary conditions. Green function

Tags: field-theory, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

Let us consider the free scalar field theory $\varphi(x,t)$ in a space of dimension 1+1, with Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag(+,-)$.  It is well known that it is described by the classical action

\begin{eqnarray}
S[\varphi]=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dxdt (\partial_{\mu}\varphi)^{2},
\end{eqnarray}

where I assumed the following boundary conditions

$\varphi(\pm \infty,t)=0$.

Now I want to decompose $\varphi(x,t)$ into a two fields, that live on a left and right hand side of our spatial line as

\begin{eqnarray}
S[\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2}]=\frac{1}{2}\int^{0}_{-\infty}dx\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dt (\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{1})^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0}dx\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dt (\partial_{\mu}\varphi_{2})^{2},
\end{eqnarray}

and also obey the following boundary conditions

\begin{equation}
\varphi_{1}(0,t)=\varphi_{2}(0,t), \;\;\varphi_{1}(-\infty,t)=\varphi_{1}(+\infty,t)=0.
\end{equation}

It is obvious that this two scalar field theory should be equivalent. In order to calculate the retarded Green function for the theory with $S[\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2}]$ one need to solve classical non-homogeneous equations of motion

\begin{eqnarray}
(-\partial^{2}_{t}+\partial^{2}_{x})G_{L}(x-x^{\prime},t)=\delta(x-x^{\prime})\delta(t),  \;x^{\prime} \in (-\infty,0] \\
(-\partial^{2}_{t}+\partial^{2}_{x})G_{R}(x-x^{\prime\prime},t)=\delta(x-x^{\prime\prime})\delta(t),  \;x^{\prime\prime} \in [0,+\infty).
\end{eqnarray}
and also use the boundary conditions, $G_{R}(0,x^{\prime\prime},t)=G_{L}(0,x^{\prime},t)$ and also $\partial_{x}G_{R}(0,x^{\prime\prime},t)=\partial_{x}G_{L}(0,x^{\prime},t)$, following from variation of the classical action over boundaries $\delta \varphi_{1}$ and $\delta \varphi_{2}$. It can be shown that in the coordinate-frequency representation, the corresponding retarded Green's functions have the form
\begin{eqnarray}
G_{L}(x,x^{\prime},\omega)=\theta(x^{\prime}-x)\frac{e^{-i\omega(x-x^{\prime})}}{i\omega}+\theta(x-x^{\prime})\frac{\cos(\omega(x-x^{\prime}))}{i\omega},\\ 
G_{R}(x,x^{\prime\prime},\omega)=\theta(x^{\prime\prime}-x)\frac{\cos(\omega(x-x^{\prime\prime}))}{i\omega}+\theta(x-x^{\prime\prime})\frac{e^{-i\omega(x^{\prime\prime}-x)}}{i\omega}.
\end{eqnarray}

How can one see the equivalence between retarded Green functions for the $S[\varphi]$ and $S[\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2}]$? And how can we also calculate the retarded Green function for the subsystems $\varphi_{1}$ and $\varphi_{2}$?

Comment: Re *"...into a two filed"*: Do you mean *"...into two fields"*?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: "filed" is not a noun.